# Changing Y-Axis Column Disrupts Project Backlog Calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, data-analysis, business-intelligence

I have a graph of the type "line and clustered column chart". On the X-axis, I have 'table'[_yearmonth_create], which is a calculated column that extracts the format "yyyy-MM" from the creation data. On the column Y-axis, I have the counts of the 'table'[ID] and 'table'[resolution_date] columns. On the line Y-axis, I have a measure that calculates the backlog of the project:

```
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('table'[ID]) - COUNT('table'[resolution_date]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('table'[_yearmonth_create]),
        'table'[_yearmonth_create] <= MAX('table'[_yearmonth_create])
    )
)
```

However, when I try to change the counts in the column Y-axis to the 'table'[p_key] column, which categorizes the type of project, the backlog measure stops working correctly.

Answer (score -1):

When you change the counts in the column Y-axis to the 'table'[p_key] column, it affects the calculation of the backlog measure because the measure is based on the counts of 'table'[ID] and 'table'[resolution_date]. The measure is designed to calculate the backlog by subtracting the count of resolved items from the count of all items.

To adjust the backlog measure to work correctly with the 'table'[p_key] column, you must modify the measure to consider the additional categorization. One approach is introducing a new filtering level based on the 'table'[p_key] column.

```
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('table'[ID]) - COUNT('table'[resolution_date]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('table'[_yearmonth_create], 'table'[p_key]),
        'table'[_yearmonth_create] <= MAX('table'[_yearmonth_create])
            && 'table'[p_key] IN VALUES('table'[p_key])
    )
)
```

The `FILTER` function includes an additional condition using the `IN` operator in the modified measure. It checks if the 'table'[p_key] value is present in the current context's selected values for the 'table'[p_key] column. This ensures that the backlog calculation considers only the relevant 'table'[p_key] values for each data point on the chart.